# NiFi - Converting JSON string to valid JSON

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Using UpdateRecord, I am trying to convert the json string to a valid json:

Input:

```
{
  "user" : "{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"TEST\"}"
}
```

Current Output:

```
{
  "user":"{id=1, name=TEST}"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "user": { 
      "id": "1", 
      "name": "TEST" 
  }
}
```

How can I fix this? Use another processor or script? Can you give me a advise?

Regards!

UpdateRecord:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason why UpdateRecord works this way is because it inferred record's schema from input records, and identified that there is a field *user* with type String.

So even if you try to use ScriptedTransformRecord instead of UpdateRecord and attempt to use Record.setValue(fieldName,convertStringToMap(previousValue)), this would convert the map to String and you still get field user with String type. (setValue() does not change type of already existing fields)

A workaround could be to enrich the record *adding* a new field, say user_map with type Map(String,String).

Alternatively, just create a new record with a new schema using [ScriptedTransformRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ScriptedTransformRecord/index.html), for example using the following groovy script where [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) is used to un-escape Json

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.nifi.serialization.SimpleRecordSchema
import org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.MapRecord
import org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.Record

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Record result = new MapRecord(new SimpleRecordSchema([]),[:]) // empty record
record.toMap().each { k,v ->
    result.setValue(k,slurper.parseText(v as String)) // adding a field Map<String,String>
}
return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JoltTransformJSON** processsor( Jolt transformation library is designed for converting a JSON to another JSON ) with spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "u": "=split('\"', @(1,user))",
      "user": "=join('',@(1,u))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "u": ""
    }
  }
]
```

where `\"` pieces are removed by using **split**, and then **join** function is used to combine the rest of the string. Extra created auxiliary attribute **u** is removed at the last step.

[image]

Edit : Depending on your edit use the following transformations

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "user": "=split('\"', @(1,user))",
      "id": "@(1,user[3])",
      "name": "@(1,user[7])"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "user": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "user"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm!  I appreciated.

Comment: For dynamic json where you dont know the object schema, follow- https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2023/04/transform-json-string-field-into-record.html?lr=1